Find a specific sample in an audio file
I'm trying to find each occurrence of a kick drum sample in a piece of music. I have a reference sample for this kick. I initially used numpy.correlate to find the locations but ran into issues for this sample. I'm also conscious that other sounds can occur in the music when the sample is used, so maybe correlate is not the best choice. I then tried a different approach but I'm also running into an issue which I don't understand.
Below is the reference sample in blue, and a different kick sample in orange (window).

I then try the following:
e1 = numpy.sum(numpy.square(window))
e2 = numpy.sum(numpy.square(window-reference))
score = e1-e2

e1 -> 1635.6357141037024
e2 -> 887.4024576374943
score -> 748.2332564662081

So I'm trying to get an idea as to how much energy is being removed from the signal if I mix it with the inverted version of the reference. I'm ignoring the length of the window since its consistent in all cases.
I then repeat for the following with the actual kick from the song in orange this time.

There is a very low frequency at this point in the audio which is causing the attack portion to compress by the looks of things.
e1 -> 432.5055914562779
e2 -> 105.92097261811263
score -> 326.5846188381653

This time I get a worse score and I don't understand why. I think the issue is the dc component of the signal but I'm not sure how to adjust my calculations to address this. That is, I wish to score this second sample much higher than the first.
UPDATE
If I use $\frac{e_{1} - e_{2}}{e_{1}}$ I do score the second sample better:
This is the score for each window as I slide across a piece of audio which is simply sample1, sample2, followed by the reference, and you can see I match sample2 and the reference.


Why should mixing the signals result in energy loss? Furthermore, in the second case the samples are very similar and subtracting similar things will result in smaller values. Am I missing something? Could you clarify a bit more on the process you use and what your goal is (subtraction that would result in high scores for similar samples doesn’t sound intuitive to me)?

@ZaellixA I updated the explanation of what I am doing to be more clear. If you mix the signal sin(x) with -sin(x) you get zero. If you mix a signal with an inverted version of itself, you should get a weak signal.

If this is a commercially produced piece of music, there will typically be compression, reverberation, etc applied to groups of channels or the entire mix that to some degree invalidate the idea of linear addition of different instruments. Further, if that sample was played back by some musical instrument, it could be modified by "key velocity" in terms of amplitude and possibly lowpass filtering.

@Knut Inge I agree that compression, reverberation, amplitude differences and low pass filtering will all result it it being very difficult for me to completely remove the sample from the track. However, I just what to detect its presence in the track. For the two signals above, when I mix the inverted reference, I get a loud sound for the first signal and a very faint signal for the second. If I apply 20*numpy.log10(numpy.abs(window-reference).max()) to roughly estimate the loudness of each of these signals, the second signal gives a much lower result.

Perhaps spectral magnitude would be a blunter (but more robust) indicator of the presence of this sample than time-domain correlation?

@Baz, I’m sorry it seems I missed the “mix with the inverted reference” part. I understand your idea. I was never a big fan of single-value indices but I do understand that they can work up to a certain extent. Now, regarding your case here, I really think that the second sample you provide does score higher than the first but in a normalised (or relative if you prefer) sense. If you normalise the results $e_{1} - e_{2}$ by $e_{1}$, you’ll see that in the second case $\frac{e_{1} - e_{2}}{e_{1}}$ is about $3/4$ while in the first is about $1/2$. Thus second “wins”.

But also, your metric works if the windows are exactly aligned. How are you dealing with this? Are you doing a sample by sample analysis? If it was me, I would do this in the frequency domain, looking at similarities in a few bands over an appropriate time window. Kick onsets have quite broad spectrum.

@Jdip I'm sliding my window along one sample at a time, from the start of the audio to the end. I can update my question soon to show the result for each window as I do this.

@ZaellixA Tried your suggestion with normalised score and updated my answer with the result, thank!. Would be interesting to incorporate log10 into this as it better matches our perception of loudness but I will need to think more about that.

@Baz, you could directly convert the scale to logarithmic with your results. I am not sure this will have some direct resemblance to the dB scale as we use it in audio/acoustics, but it will still be in logarithmic scale. It may even help differentiate the occurrences of the kick drums (or whatever it is that you are “looking for”).
